# How to apped in table format using String builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a table format in the body of email.

[image: In my mail it is coming like this . Not in a table format]

This is how I do the appending

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<td>ID</td>");
sb.Append("<td>STATUS</td>");
sb.Append("</tr>");
//sb.Append("</table>");
//sb.Append(" < table border = '1' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' width = '100%' >");
foreach (var item in mylist)
        {
          sb.Append("<tr>");
          sb.Append("<td>" + item.message + "</td>");
          sb.Append("<td>" + item.transactionid + "</td>");
          sb.Append("</tr>");

         }
sb.Append("</table>");
```

---

```
var sendmail = new MailAddress("", "Akhil");
var receiver = new MailAddress("", "Buddy");

var subject = "Request for Asset!!";
var body = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Above it is the screen shot how I getting the result in email

Comment: IT looks like the way you are sending the email, not the string it self that is the problem. You need to look at that code instead and figure out how to flag the email as HTML instead of plaintext.

Comment: Side note: you may want to read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting before diving into wonderful world of generating HTML from user provided content.

Answer (score 0):

If you using System.Web.Mail then put messageg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

If you using System.Net.Mail then put message.IsBodyHtml = true; .

IsBodyHtml & MailFormat.Html states that your message is HTML formatted.

Comment: I am using System.Net.Mail

Comment: make IsBodyHtml  flag true for System.Net.Mail

message.IsBodyHtml = true;

Answer (score 0):

```
> This is not a true way, first you should add the HTML file, then after create a table inside the file.

Now attach a file with StringBuilder.

## Here is my send email with attachment  code ##

    StringBuilder sbMailBody = new StringBuilder();
    sbMailBody.Append(Server.MapPath("~/Content/fielname.html"));

    var sendmail = new MailAddress("", "Akhil");
    var receiver = new MailAddress("", "Buddy");

    var subject = "Request for Asset!!";
    var body = sbMailBody.ToString();
```